# ADO ADDBTIMESTAMP format changes

Tags: sql-server, ado

OK, so, here's an odd one, which is causing me to lose what little hair I have left.

We have some code that uses ADO to pull data from SQL Server. The code's been in place for 7 or 8 years now, and hasn't been touched for quite a while.

In the function, where we check the returned field's type for some conversion, we have this:

```
  case ( fieldType = ADDBTIMESTAMP$ )
     * // A date/time stamp (yyyymmddhhmmss plus a fraction 
     * // in billionths)
     * // Looksd like we're just getting MM/DD/YYYY
     * // ooh no sometimes we get 6/25/2010 11:35:00 AM
```

Basically, this is saying that when the field's type is ADDBTIMESTAMP (or 135), then for whatever reason, the date is being returned MM/DD/YYYY sometimes with, and sometimes without a time stamp.

This morning, all date fields are now returning values YYYY-MM-DD (dashes included).

I haven't changed this code.  The network people swear up and down that they haven't updated or modified SQL Server. My workstation is Win10, so who knows what's changed on that, but I don't see any indication of updates for the past few days.

Obviously, something's changed, considering we're now getting the data back in a what should be the correct format, but for the life of me, I can't see what could have happened.

Any help or tips or psychiatric recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: we dont see your code or the machines or the sql server, we dont know if the dates come as a string or not, but it all makes me think; collation changed, or more likely the machine where the dates are generated had the "culture" settings changed.

Comment: +1 @RicardoC.  In addition to those points; can you provide sample records from the database?  What data type is used in SQL Server?

Comment: They finally gave me access to some of the other machines. Turns out my workstation is the only one with the problem.  They're running a salad of operating systems.  No two workstations have the same OS or version or anything.  They've decided to uninstall updates on my machine one at a time until the problem goes away.  I'd have thought it would have been easier to update my workstation to match a machine with a later version of Win10 that works, but what do I know?

Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Thanks for the revisions, @Marc_s.  I just cut & pasted the comment from the code.

How do I make this closed or answered, or just have people ignore the question, since it's turning into a workstation configuration problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's a configuration issue on the workstation I'm using.  No other workstation appears to have the problem.  I don't think I'll ever find out what happened.  To be honest, now that I've looked at the code, which I've never needed to before, I'm more concerned that it's always been returning wrong on every machine for the last 7 or 8 years.

It's things like this that make me want to go into a less stressful line of work, like opening a restaurant.

Thanks.